# Installed postscript font into osx, cannot see in inskape (x11 app)

Tags: macos, graphics, fonts

I purchased a font on fonts.com and installed the font-suitcase on osx.  I then restarted my mac.

TextEdit, a native osx app recognizes the font. However; my free vector graphics program: Inkscape does not. Neither does the Java based OpenOffice.

I need a solution: either a native osx vector graphics program ,or a way to get the free graphics programs to recognize my font.

I also need a hug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you do not need to restart your machine for the font to take affect. I usually just restart the application I am trying to load the font from. There may be an issue with the applications you mentioned since TextEdit recognizes the font; the vector application and OpenOffice may not recognize the type of font you installed.